# Azure media player unable to play DRM content as a MS teams app

Tags: iframe, browser, microsoft-teams, drm, azure-media-player

I'm trying to create a small app where I'm going to play a DRM encoded video using azure media player. It is showing error code "(0x10500001)"

[enter image description here][1]

FYI- Player is playing DRM video on all browsers perfectly.
Here is the URL for JSFiddle for AMP DRM Play - https://jsfiddle.net/f0pewmqz/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Azure Media Player</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample: DRM - PlayReady, Widevine, and FairPlay (no token)</h1>
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"> </video>
<script>
var myOptions = {
autoplay: true,
controls: true,
width: "640",
height: "400",
poster: ""
}; 
var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
myPlayer.src([{ src: "//ampvideos.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/9b77ed82-94af-41bc-b08b-537e7a530eb6/sintel_trailer-1080p_fp.ism/manifest", type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml", protectionInfo: [{ type: "PlayReady" }, { type: "Widevine" },{ type: "FairPlay", certificateUrl: "//yourdomain/fairplay.der" }] }, ]);
</script>
</body>
```

To quickly replicate the issue on MS Teams Desktop app and Browser app:

1. Copy the URL - https://dhananjaytest.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-02-14-jhqwb.html
2. In MS Teams select add Tab option (+).
3. Select Website option.
4. Add URL and save.

If you are using Teams on browser you can replicate this by following link and follow the above steps.
https://dhananjaytest.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-02-14-jhqwb.html

Comment: We also tried to repro this issue and are getting same error using Teams desktop https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnOdZ.png `Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.4378` But using Teams web getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wbev.png . In console getting below error message: `Refused to display 'https://jsfiddle.net/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` Please ensure that you adhere to the following prerequisites: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

Comment: Hey @Prasad-MSFT, Sorry for the trouble. Yes you are right, JSFiddle does not run in iframe. But Issue can be easily replicated on MS Teams App desktop. I've updated question details now and also the link for browser replication steps.

Comment: Does anyone know what browser is inside of Teams and if it has a EME CDM module for widevine or PlayReady?  This seems like more of a Teams browser question - not an AMP or AMS question.... if the browser in Teams does not have DRM in it, it won't work.

Comment: @SonuGupta - Yes using the above provided url in browser it gives same issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZylPz.png The url doesn't seem to be iframeable

Comment: Use of the Website tab option doesn't support this. You need to build a Teams App and leverage the device permissions functionality to request the media permission:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cmobile1#specify-permissions Once the app is given the media permission, you can add the encrypted-media attribute to its iframe which allows it to play DRM content.